# Llenar JQuery Datatable según pagina

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, datatables

Estoy trabajando en **PHP**. Tengo una gran cantidad de datos para mostrar en una tabla Datatables y la carga total toma mucho tiempo. Para optimizar este proceso deseo mostrar los registros por partes según el usuario vaya avanzando en las páginas (1, 2, 3, etc).
El proceso sería algo así: Si el usuario eliger ver 50 registros por página, en la página 1 aparecerán los primeros 50 registros (1-50), luego cuando avance a la segunda página mostrar (51-100), cuando avance a la página tres (101-150) y así sucesivamente. No tengo idea de como podría codificar este proceso.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución a lo que planteas es el uso de una paginación. Para esto, Datatable  cuenta con una opción dentro del objeto de configuración que es *pagin*, la cual toma dos valores *true* (valor por defecto) o *false*. También puedes configurar la opción *pageLength* asignado un entero que indica el número de filas por página.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "paging": true,
    "pageLength": 50  
});
```

Otra de las opciones para cuando se manejan grandes cantidades de datos, es usar
*Server-side processing (Procesamiento del lado del servidor)*. En este caso, todo el trabajo pesado se realiza en el servidor. Es decir, DataTables se encarga de enviar una serie de variables al servidor las cuales son necesarias para llevar a cabo el procesamiento y luego éste envía como respuesta los datos en el formato requerido por DataTables.

Server Side processing: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side

pageLength: https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength

paging: https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging